# python subprocess terminal mac osx

Tags: python, macos, terminal, subprocess, popen

longtime lurker, first time poster.

I know there are quite a few examples throughout the interweb on using subprocess, however I am yet to find one that explains the steps I need to take to birth a new terminal window, and send it commands. There are plenty of posts that give workarounds to launch tools and scripts via a direct subprocess call, but I have not found any that actually answer the original questions of how to send a command properly to terminal.

In my case, I need to open a new terminal window, then send the path to a particular version of an application, and finally the path to the file I wish to open in that application.

I know how to use subprocess to call the applications needed directly (without opening a visible terminal), how to open a new terminal with subprocess, and how to call either the application path OR the file path (have not been able to get both to execute together using --args for open() or any other workaround I have found).

I have been unable to send terminal a command once I have opened it. The following is a simple version of opening a new instance of terminal and sending it ls, which does not work.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['open', '-a', 'Terminal', '-n'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

output = p.communicate(input='ls')
print(output)
```

This is most likely a trivial issue and I am simply missing something, but I have been unable to find the information or an example that illustrates what I need and I am beginning to get frustrated with it, so I figured I would ask for help.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated! TIA

Comment: This is unfortuately not easy like you think. Terminal opens it's own subprocesses (bash for example) and communicates with them directly. Sending anything to stdin of Terminal doesn't get to those other processes. You're probably approaching this problem incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks korylprince, I am going to try to go about it differently. Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 3):

@cody

My response to your answer was too long, therefore I am making an answer to respond:

1. You are correct, if you enter it the way you offered, it flags an error, and if you put the -n before Terminal it still flags an error. However, if you enter it the way I showed in the first example (-n after Terminal) "open" calls a new instance of app bundle Terminal, even if one is already open.

As for 2-3, that was kind of what my research was leading me to believe, but I was hoping I was wrong or missed something somewhere and someone here could clarify. Sadly, I wasn't mistaken…

I should probably expand on what I am trying to do, as maybe it will help generate a better way to accomplish it via Python.

I have created a tool that launches application files based on the movie, scene, and shot an artist is working on. For some applications, like Nuke and Houdini, opening from Terminal gives you a wealth of information that the artist would be blind to otherwise, so we would like to give the artist the option to launch the file they have chosen in a Terminal. That terminal has to be standalone, and a new instance of Terminal, because the app I have created must persist after the launch in order to open other shots in different applications without making the user routinely open the app.

Parsing the necessary info, building the commands, and launching a new Terminal that launches the desired application were all trivial. Doing the same with the desired file was trivial as well. The issue arises when a particular version of the app is chosen, and I have not been able to pass the newly birthed instance of Terminal with more than a single command (honestly the syntax of my OSX command may be the issue as well, will post further down).

I can get the following two commands to work without issue:

```
p = Popen(['open', '-a', 'Terminal', '-n', '--args', '/Applications/Nuke6.3v8/Nuke6.3v8.app/Nuke6.3v8'])

p = Popen(['open', '-a', 'Terminal', '-n', '--args', '/Path/to/Nuke/File.nk'])
```

I cannot get the following to work properly:

```
p = Popen(['open', '-a', 'Terminal', '-n', '--args', '/Applications/Nuke6.3v8/Nuke6.3v8.app/Nuke6.3v8', '/Path/to/Nuke/File.nk'])
```

From there my thought was possibly that I should launch the Terminal in the Popen, then pass the commands I needed. That did not work, and then I came here lol

Thanks again for any help! Just knowing that I cannot send to the commands I want to Terminal is saving me a ton of time that would have been spent on continuos frustrated research.

Answer (score 2):

1. First, I doubt that command you are trying to run will run at all.
   Did you try it in terminal first? `open -an Terminal` will give you
   an error. It probably should be something like `open -n
   /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`
2. Second, @korylprince is right: `open` itself will create new process
   of `Terminal` and exit. So you are linking pipe with wrong process.
3. Third, at the moment of passing `ls` to the stdin that process
   doesn't exist already (unless you will pass -W option to the `open`,
   but it certainly will not help due to the 2 problem).

So I see only one opportunity to do this: via AppleScript. You can create an AppleScript string, something like next:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Terminal"
        keystroke "ls"
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

and then run this script via `osascript -e '<your_script>'` via Popen.
Yes it is quite tricky (I'd say it is a hack)
Yes there probably will be problems with passing multiline string to Popen and with determining correct Terminal window.
But it is possible.